# "A start to answering..." (To + verb + ing)

Tags: prepositional-phrases, gerund-clauses

I'm a native speaker, and I'm having trouble figuring out if something I said is just bad English or if it is correct (but just sounds strange).

A friend asked me a question, and I said, "I'm not completely sure, but check that website out. That's a start to answering your question."

I looked at this [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38964), but I could not see where "start to answering" made sense grammatically.

It doesn't sound as bad to me if I say, "That'll serve as a start to answering your question."

Can someone tell me of that sentence is right or wrong? If so, what part of speech is "answering" in that question?

Comment: A gerund used as a noun.  Perfectly acceptable, I believe.

Comment: To add: the "*to*" in your phrase is a preposition.  You could use "*of*" there as well.

Comment: I know what a gerund is, but I don't see how answering is a noun in this sentence.

Comment: "A start to a (beautiful) friendship" - "a start to <something>", what follows 'to' is a noun.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. "To answering" is a prepositional phrase right? Also, if you write your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the final answer.:)

Comment: Yes, prepositional phrase used as adjective, I think, since 'start' is a noun here, not a verb. You have practically answered your own question.  I'll try writing something up (unless somebody gets there before me :-)).

Comment: Check out this Google Books link as [a start to answering](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+start+to+answering%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence, the part "*to answering your question*" is a prepositional phrase used as adjective (to accompany 'start'), I believe.  In it '*answering*' is a gerund used as a noun.  More on prepositional phrases you can find [here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/Prepositional-Phrases.html).

As an alternative you can use the preposition "*of*" instead of "*to*", although both are acceptable.  Examples of similar uses are, "a start *to* a wonderful friendship", "a decent start *to* a long day".